# azurerm_virtual_network.main is object with no attributes

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a Terraform script:

```
variable "locations" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    vm1 = "North Europe"
    vm2 = "West Europe"
  }
}
...
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.azurerm_resource_group_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  for_each             = var.locations
  name                 = "${each.key}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.azurerm_resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main[each.key].name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}
...
```

Error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on environment.tf line 33, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal":
  33:   virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main[each.key].name
    |----------------
    | azurerm_virtual_network.main is object with no attributes
    | each.key is "vm2"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I know that I can modify (hard-code) with "${each.key}-network" the line 33, but why it doesn't work? If I hard code it, it also throws an error at the next uses of the same type of declaration. It is interesting, that sometimes it plans without errors.

Comment: I was able to use the `for_each` syntax the way you configured for creating AWS resources, but don't have easy access to Azure credentials.

Can you update your post to include the Terraform version you're using?

It also looks like you have a mix of Terraform 11 and Terraform 12 syntax, e.g., `"${var.azurerm_resource_group_name}"` (TF 11) should be `var.azurerm_resource_group_name` (TF 12).

Finally, if you can update the code snippet to be independently reproducible, i.e., provide a `azurerm_resource_group_name` with a default value.

Comment: There is no problem with the code. Are you sure it does not work?